# Does there exist a big graph with that property?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a graph with the  chromatic number greater than $2013$ and all the cycles of length greater than $2013 $ too?

Comment: This sounds like a contest question.  Is the contest closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This can be proved by probabilistic method, which was first introduced by Paul Erdos. See [here](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture13.pdf) for example.

Comment: Cute. You beat me by 20 seconds and we even chose the same link.

Comment: Great minds think alike right?  It will happen sometimes on a forum like this.  If the link was different, I would have suggested editing the existing answer to include the new link.  Oh well.

Comment: @mrf: haha. I just search in google with chromatic number and girth, and that's the first link I can find. I guess you did the same thing. In any case, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for every $k$ and every $l$ there are graphs with chromatic number $>k$ And girth $>l$. This is a well-known theorem, usually proved using "the probabilistic method".

See for example [this link](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture13.pdf)